# Android DrawerLayout - too slow upon item click

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want my navigation drawer to open the fragment smoothly upon click and close itself without any lag.

Here is the code -

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

            // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

            drawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });

            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {

                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            }

            onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));

            @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            /* clear backstack of all elements but the last one
             * which is the car keys screen
             */
            for (int i = 1; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
                fm.popBackStack();
            }
    }

        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_settings).setVisible(false);


        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

        }

        if (menuItem.getGroupId() == R.id.group_top) {

            navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.group_bottom, false, true);
            navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.group_top, true, true);
        } else {

            navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.group_bottom, true, true);
            navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.group_top, false, true);
        }

        //Update highlighted item in the navigation menu
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        if (fragment != null) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView);
            setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack("fragment")
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }



        return false;
    }
```

This is in the `MainActivity`.

Where am I going wrong? Why does it not run smoothly?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: navigation drawer before closing

Answer (score 0):

try putting it in a thread with a little delay so it will finish his other commands , like :

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              if(drawerLayout!=null)
                  drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView);
        }
    }, 150);
```